# Some differences between xvalue and prvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, lifetime, xvalue, prvalue

I've been carefully studying C++ catogories recently. The difference between lvalue and rvalue seems to be clear, but I got confused when it comes to prvalue and xvalue.
Given the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::move;
class Type {
public:
    int value;
    Type(const int &value=0) :value(value) {}
    Type(const Type &type) :value(type.value){}
    Type(Type &&type) noexcept :value(type.value) {}
    Type &operator= (const Type &type) {
        value = type.value;
        return *this;
    }
    Type &operator=(Type &&type) noexcept{
        value = type.value;
        return *this;
    }
};
Type foo1(const Type &value) {
    return Type(value);
}
Type &&foo2(const Type &value) {
    return Type(value);
}
int main() {
    Type bar1(123);
    cout << foo1(bar1).value << endl;
    cout << foo2(bar1).value << endl;
    Type bar2;
    bar2 = foo1(bar1);
    cout << bar2.value << endl;
    bar2 = foo2(bar1);
    cout << bar2.value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Running the example, the console puts:
**123

123

123

-858993460**

Can anyone explan why it gives an unexpected value in the last output?
What feature does this example show about xvalue?

Comment: `foo2` returns a reference to a local variable, that is destroyed. So the reference is dangling. It doesn't really have anything to do with `prvalue`s vs `xvalue`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo2` is returning reference bound to temporary which is destroyed immediately; it always returns a dangled [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary).

> a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a return statement is not extended: it is destroyed immediately at the end of the return expression. Such function always returns a dangling reference.

Dereference on the returned reference like `foo2(bar1).value` and `bar2 = foo2(bar1);` leads to UB; anything is possible.

On the other hand, `foo1` doesn't have such issue. The return value is moved from the temporary object.

Comment: Do you mean that even though foo2(bar1).value gives the right result, it's just a coincidence of an undefined behavior?

Comment: @true_mogician Yes, the behavior is not guaranteed.

Comment: @true_mogician BTW [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mGUkVhdXRiQEaoUm) gives segmentation fault on `foo2(bar1).value`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple explanation. Consider this textbook example from pre-C++0x times:

```
T& f()
{
    T t;
    return t;
}

// ...

T& val = f();
cout << val; // <--- SIGSEGV here
```

You are not surprised that this snippet crashed, right? You returned a reference (which is, under the hood, nothing more than a glorified pointer) to a local object which was destroyed before the function even returned, thus dooming `val` to become a dangling reference.

Now consider:

```
T&& f()
{
    T t;
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

// ...

T&& val = f();
cout << val; // <--- SIGSEGV here
```

In terms of object lifetimes, this is **exactly the same** as before. Rvalue reference is not some brand new tool for magically moving objects around. It's the same old **reference** (read: glorified pointer). Nothing changed - you still returned an address of a destroyed object.

And I assume everyone is on board with that `std::move` is nothing more than a glorified `static_cast<T&&>`, so in case it's used the result is the same:

```
T&& f()
{
    T t;
    return std::move(t);
}

// ...

T&& val = f();
cout << val; // <--- SIGSEGV here
```

This example is 99.9% identical to the previous one.

<sub><sub>(The 0.1% difference is, e.g., in that in the first two examples GCC **knows** that the code is screwed up and actually returns a null reference that's guaranteed to crash on first use; while in the last example, since `std::move` is a function, it can't be sure so it obediently returns the bad address).</sub></sub>